# Separating two lights from one switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, multiway-switch

I recently converted one big room into two. The original lighting in the room was two ceiling fans on one switch. When building the separating wall I pre-installed a new switch and stubbed up about 20 ft of wire into the attic. How do I break the connection between the two so that both lights are independent of each other?
Thanks

Comment: What problem do you have? You have stated your goal, but no details on the challenge you have accomplishing the goal.

Comment: Due to the fact there are a few ways of connecting lights to switches, we will need pictures of how the lights and switch are wire to give the right answer.  Take pictures with the breaker off.

Comment: Ten to one, the closest fan/light to the switch will be the most important to see how the wires are connected and will be the one where the work needs to be done.  It depends on how the power is passed to the fans.